# Modify format of sqllite select columns

Tags: sqlite, output, built-in

I am pretty new to SqlLite db. I have the following table along with its data. I want to modify the columns data which appears as output.

```
CREATE TABLE students (studentId TEXT, firstName TEXT, studentNo TEXT);
INSERT INTO students VALUES ("6b975012-ec43-496e-b1df-44a214437287" ,"Virat" ,"530642685”);
```

The following select query should return

```
SELECT studentNo from students;
```

XXXXX2685

I have tried using built in functions available with SqlLite without any luck.

```
SELECT REPLACE(studentNo, '', 'X') as Student_SSN from students;
```

Could anyone please let me know how to achieve this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select studentNo,
       format('%.*c', length(studentNo)-4, 'X') || substr(studentNo,-4,4) as student_SSN
  from students;
```

Result:

```
studentNo|student_SSN|
---------+-----------+
530642685|XXXXX2685  |
```

If the number of 'X' is not important, use a string literal:

```
select studentNo,
       'XXXXX' || substr(studentNo,-4,4) as student_SSN
  from students;
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `%.*c` and where can i get details of all wildcard characters.
thanks